# 301 Redirect to static html from a single parameter php page

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to change my page i.e. **oldpage.php?id=11** to **http://www.example.com/newpage.html**.

Can any one please help. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

If you have mod_rewrite installed / enabled then this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=11$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.php$ http://www.example.com/newpage.html? [L,R=301]
```